# UnauthorizedAccessException - Access Image File After Displaying BitmapImage of same File via URI

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a flipview of images, and each flipview item's image is binded to a bitmapimage which is constructed via a URI, e.g.

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new URI(...));
```

I want the flipview of images to load only images that are selected, so in the `flipview_selectionchanged` event, I set the urisource of the selected image, and just make every other `BitmapImage.UriSource = null` as long as it's not the selected index. This works perfectly fine.

Also, whenever I instantiate an image, I type the following:

```
BitmapImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
```

because I want to try to access the file that is associated with that bitmapimage/uri later in my code.

And whenever a user hits this special button, the current selected image in the flipview's file is attempted to be accessed, but then I get a "`UnauthorizedAccessException`" for some reason.

I already tried making the current image's `UriSource = null`. I say `GC.Collect()` as well. But even after doing all of this I still get UnauthorizedAccessException.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnauthorizedAccessException while saving a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000137/unauthorizedaccessexception-while-saving-a-file)

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I don't think it's a duplicate. See here where someone answered for me: [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/bc9aa758-f211-468b-8168-a671b7a0c8b4/uwp-creating-bitmapimage-with-uri-accessing-file-from-same-uri-gives-exception?forum=wpdevelop#a6c03d5f-5bf6-48ea-8776-dadfc8eb66af). He says using Uri should work in W10 UWP, even without setting Uri to null, but when I try it it doesn't work.